# Cannot center button text in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

i am following a tutorial and noticed that my button text is not aligned to the center of the button. I have tried to play around with

```
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

and had no luck

this is my full code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".StartingPoint" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your total is 0"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@id/bAdd"
    android:layout_width="250sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add one"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvDisplay"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the view

[image: view]

Comment: means do you want to show text of button to centre of it?

Comment: Your xml is absolutely fine. I tried it in my editor. Try making a new xml and copy pasting it into that file.

Comment: @PiyushGupta, i want the text to appear in the center of the button, see uploaded pic.

Comment: @eric247, tried that but still same problem.

Comment: but i have tested this code and its working fine in my app

Comment: and if you are using Relative Layout then don't to need  use android:layout_gravity

Comment: Hishalv where is the subtract one button's code? u making it dynamically ? and on which u screen u testing it

Comment: @PiyushGupta, thanks i tried to restart eclipse twice and it did not work, only after rebooting my pc did it center text. Thanks guys

Comment: I just cleaned and restarted Eclipse, and it worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok
First you can change this line...

```
android:id="@id/bAdd"
```

for this line

```
android:id="@+id/bAdd"
```

Second use "dp" instead "sp". You can use "sp" for text size but for width or height use "dp".

but I really don't know why you are having this problem.

I just copy/paste your code and worked very well for me.

Here is the results with the button to subtract

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StartingPoint" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Your total is 0"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvDisplay"
    android:text="Add one"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSub"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bAdd"
    android:text="Subtract one"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try these options.

1. Clean your project (Project > Clean)
2. Close the xml and open it again
3. Close Eclipse and open it again
4. Create a new Android XML File file using the same code
5. Try to preview all screens on Graphical Layout Tab.

I really don't know if this will solve your problem but you can try. Sometimes the api do same crazy things.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: @Hishalv, I figured if you did something like that (close eclipse or the xml) your code would work.

Answer (score 0):

I tested you code and i only had to add "+" at

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
```

to make an error disspear. The preview look fine, with text centered on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all these paddings.

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: Thanks, i had to reboot my pc for it to work. text is correctly centered now

Comment: And hisalv one more suggestion, don't use (sp) in button's width . use 250dp . we use sp for textsizes

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".StartingPoint" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Your total is 0"
android:textSize="40sp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
 />

<Button
android:id="@+id/bAdd"
android:layout_width="250sp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Add one"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:layout_below="@+id/tvDisplay"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/bSub"
android:layout_width="250sp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Subtract one"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:layout_below="@+id/bAdd"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```